# How to implement Lock with only AtomicInteger?

Tags: java, multithreading

During job interview I was asked the following question:

How to implement `Lock` interface if all concurrent primitives we have are `AtomicInteger`. I.e. no `synchronized` block, `volatile` variables `java util.concurrent` etc...

Of course, the first thing I thought was something like the follwoing:

```
public static class ReentrantLock{
    private final AtomicInteger locked= new AtomicInteger();
    public void lock(){
        if(!locked.compareAndSet(0, 1))
            //throw new LockedException
    }

    public void unlock(){
        if(!locked.compareAndSet(1, 0))
            //throw new NotLockedException
    }
}
```

But this implementation cannot keep track of the `Thread` which acquired the lock. Any ideas how to implement it just with `AtomicInteger`? With `sun.misc.Unsafe` it is possible, but what about without using `Unsafe`?

The problem is we cannot keep track of the current thread and change the field `locked` atomically.

Comment: "But this implementation cannot keep track of the Thread which acquired the lock." did the interviewer say that it needs to keep track of the thread that acquired the lock?

Comment: You would need to implement a busy wait: `while (!counter.compareAndSet(0, 1));`. Not sure if reentrancy is possible though.

Comment: counter <=?=> locked ?

Comment: @AmiHollander Fixed

Comment: @shmosel, if you have a non-reentrant lock, you can use it in the implementation of a reentrant lock.

Comment: @jameslarge How?

Comment: @shmosel That would be a good subject for a new question.  I can't paste code examples here.  Short answer though;  You can use a simple (non-reentrant) mutex lock to protect the fields of an object.  So, imagine a "ReentrantLock" object...  It knows whether or not it is locked, and if locked, how many times, and its methods are all thread-safe because they are protected by the simple mutex.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can also get the unique id of the calling thread using `Thread.currentThread().getId()` and set it to some static `AtomicInteger` called threadId. If the current threadId is same with your threadId or not, you can decide what to do.

Comment: @JoachimSauer, how about using two AtomicIntegers?

Comment: Anyway we cannot change the field `locked` and keep track of the current thread atomically. This is the the problem

Comment: @JoachimSauer you are right but somehow we can store `long` in `ìnteger` if we have to?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following does the trick for a non re-entrant lock:

```
class AtomicIntegerLock {
    private final AtomicInteger token = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private Thread owner;

    public void lock() {
        while (!token.compareAndSet(0, 1)) {
            Thread.yield();
        }
        owner = Thread.currentThread();
    }

    public void unlock() {
        if (owner == Thread.currentThread()) {
            owner = null;
            token.set(0);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalMonitorStateException();
        }
    }
}
```

While initially one might think that the `owner` field needs to be volatile it turns out this is not necessary. The happens before relation for actions on the same thread ensures that callers see consistent values.

According to the same logic you could add (a non volatile) counter field for making the lock re-entrant.

Comment: So it fails if we call `lock` and `unlock` from different threads

Comment: @СашаДанилин, yes it fails when unlock is called from a different thread. This is how most `Lock` implementations behave. However this is not mandatory according to the general contract of `unlock`. Dropping this part simplifies the implementation as then we do not need to remember the owner of the lock.

Comment: @michid Can it be converted into reentrant lock by incrementing the AtomicInteger, and adding the `if` statement `owner == Thread.currentThread()`? I tried something like this but it didn't work

Comment: @Daniel, I believe you could make this work. You need to be careful to only modify the counter when you own the lock and ensure to decrement it the same number of times in unlock.